# Sidebar on Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I've just started playing with Eclipse RCP.

A few things that I would like to accomplish:

1. How do I maximize the initial size of the application?
2. I would like to create a sidebar type view on my left and would like to fix the size of that view and remove any title bar, minimize/ maximize/ close from that side-bar.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some tutorials like Vogella's are a must read ;)

- [RCP Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html)
- [JFace Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html)

For 1/, this has to do with the `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer`, like:

```
configurer.getWindow().getShell().setMaximized( true );
```

on `postWindowOpen( IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer )` of your `WorkbenchAdvisor`.

This [thread has other alternatives](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t31806.html#91881644).

For 2/, you can do it declaratively or by program, like [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg03378.html) shows:

> You can do it in `plugin.xml`, by providing extension to point `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` by specifying `showTitle="false"` on the view element.
>
> or You can do it programmatically in Your PerspectiveFactory implementation:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    ...
    layout.addStandaloneView(View.ID,  false,
            IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, editorArea);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Other layouts are possible, as illustrated in http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg03962.html

Comment: See also bug 5684 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5684#c9) on the "titleness" of views.

Comment: Wow, thank you all friends for the reply.  I shall try them now.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix the size of the sidebar to a say number rather than a ratio?

Comment: @Rabin: http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm seems to indicate only a ratio (but if you know the initial global window size and the size of your view, you can easily compute said ratio)

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar can be create via using viewpart and adjust in perspective using IPerspective in right or left side and given window size.

Comment: Quality of the answer is too low. Provide more detailed and technical description please.